# How to query a cell reference that contains 'text'

Tags: google-sheets

I want to search specific product name from a range of data having 2 col, col1 is product name and col2 is product category.

```
=QUERY([range 2 columns], "SELECT [col2 category] WHERE ([col1 product names] contains '[specific product name]')")
```

When i tried an excel query by inserting a text value in the specific product name like 'Alpha' the query works.

But if i insert "&F2&" it gives empty output. I don't want to insert the text manually. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `'"&F2&"'` in place of `"&F2&"`

General Example: `=query({A2:B5},"where Col2 contains '"&D1&"'")`

Comment: Can i use this, inside an ARRAYFORMULA?

Comment: care to share a sample sheet with realistic demo data maybe and desired output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture on how to best amend the current formula...

Comment: col1 categories [A, B, C, D],            
col2 product name [Alpha, Beta, Gamma].

So 'Alpha' name can come under category 'A' and 'B' as well.

I want a column where it will search that 'Alpha' comes under which categories.

Expected Outcome - [A, B]